# How to print the following Multi-Dimensional array in Java Script?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array (the code is written in Java) :

```
String[][] a = new String[3][2];
a[0][0] = "1"; 
a[0][1] = "2"; 

a[1][0] = "1";  
a[1][1] = "2"; 

a[2][0] = "1";
a[2][1] = "2";
```

and what I want to do is to print 111222 and I accomplished that in Java by doing this:

```
for (int i=0;i < a[i].length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j <a.length;j++){
        System.out.print(a[j][i]);
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent of this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the equivalent code in Javascript (no space its not a script version of java)

! edit missed the particulars of the loops, fixed now

```
var a = [];
a.push(["1", "2"]);
a.push(["1", "2"]);
a.push(["1", "2"]);

for(var i = 0; i < a[i].length; i++) {
  for(var z = 0; z < a.length; z++) {
    console.log(a[z][i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not right, it will print the array like this (121212) what i want is to print something like the following 111222

Comment: the for loop bit is the same as java write it as you whant

Comment: i didn't se that you had nested it strangely is that really the behavior you want?

Comment: Yes, i want to use it for a special purpose function.

Comment: wow, can some one elaborate on this code.  Beautiful as it is, I dont understand how `a[z][i]` is printing what its printing.  Thanks

Comment: If you're going to correct the OP, then note that it's "JavaScript," not "Javascript."

Answer (score 6):

```
var arr =[
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
        ],arrText='';

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                arrText+=arr[i][j]+' ';
            }
            console.log(arrText);
            arrText='';
        }
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

js is very powerfull ; just use spread operator

```js
mat = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]

mat.forEach(v=>console.log(...v));
```

// output
run the code see the output.

1 2 3

3 4 5

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) { document.write(a[i][j]); }
}
```

Though it would be smarter to add all the strings together and the print them out as one (could add to an element or alert it out.)

Comment: again this will print the array like this (121212) what i want is to print something like the following 111222

Answer (score 2):

- In javascript you can create multi dimensional array using single
  dimensional arrays.
- For every element in an array assign another array to make it multi
  dimensional.

```js
    // first array equivalent to rows 
    let a = new Array(3);
    
    // inner array equivalent to columns
    for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      a[i] = new Array(2);
    }
    
    // now assign values
    a[0][0] = "1"; 
    a[0][1] = "2"; 

    a[1][0] = "1";  
    a[1][1] = "2"; 

    a[2][0] = "1";
    a[2][1] = "2";
    
    /* console.log appends new line at end. So concatenate before     printing */
    
    let out="";
    for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      for(let j=0; j<a[i].length; j++) {
        out = out + a[i][j];
      }
    }
    console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [];

a[0] = [];
a[0][0] = "1";
a[0][1] = "2";

a[1] = [];
a[1][0] = "1";
a[1][1] = "2";

a[2] = [];
a[2][0] = "1";
a[2][1] = "2";

for (i = 0; i < a[i].length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        document.write(a[j][i]);
    }
}
```