# How to print value stored in an array in localstorage in html

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, local-storage

I have stored the some values in string form in an array `oldItems` in the localstorage. Now I want to display that set of string at different places in html. So all I need is the access to all the strings differently.

`var test2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("oldItems"));`

where I am defining an array test2 and I am printing using `id` like

```
<tr> 
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td>  <p id="test2[0]"></p>  </td>
</tr>
```

But the following thing is not printing the values stored in the array . Is there anything wrong in the code? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually, your `HTML` will be parsed before your javascript. So, you will have to write a function in javascript to populate values at appropriate places. Although, this is not absolutely necessary, but a good practice. Makes its easy to maintain / change your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

In `<p id="__here__"` you **cannot** state JavaScript statements (the `test2[0]` you have). They go in the `<script>` element. If you want to do this, use:

```
var p = document.querySelector("__any__specific__selector__for__p");
p.id = test2[0];
```

Comment: okay. Like I have a table and I want to print values stored in that array, So how should I do so? Is their any other way to do that?

Comment: You are very confusing: "Like I have a **table** and I want to print values stored in that **array**" ? I recommend to edit your question if this your new query.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually all i need to do is print the value stored in the array in a table in my html file. So how should I do that? Is there any other way?

Comment: Note: an array cannot be in a table, I think if you want to print a multi-dimensional array, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7652549/2675672

Answer (score 1):

Following script may be help you :

```
<script>
function displayValues()
{
    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('barcodes')) || [];

    for(var i=oldItems.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        var html=document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("allCodes").innerHTML=html+"<br>"+oldItems[i].barcode;      
    }    
    }
displayValues();
</script>
```