# how to return to be output for mutlidimention array in FUNCTION

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

can multidimensions array return in function to display the all value in the 2dimentions array ??

```js
function display(arr) {


}

const result = display([
["str", 1],
["str2", 2],
["str3", 3]
])

const result2 = display([
["str", 1],
["str2", 2],
["str3", 3],
["str4", 4]
])

const result3 = display([
["str", 1],
["str2", 2]
])

console.log(result)
console.log(result2)
console.log(result3)
```

i know `console.log` might work, how about return it in function ?

the output i want it `// str = 1, str2 = 2, str3 = 3`
`// str = 1, str2 = 2, str3 = 3 , str4 = 4`
`// str = 1, str2 = 2`

Comment: `return arr.map(([str, value]) => str + " = " + value).join(", ");`

Comment: `return arr.map((v) => v[1]);`

Comment: BTW, you should let `display` handle the logging itself, so instead of `return`ing a string that you need to log yourself later, just call `console.log` directly inside `display`. Unless of course you want to use the resulting string elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the following Multi-Dimensional array in Java Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652342/how-to-print-the-following-multi-dimensional-array-in-java-script)

Comment: @messerbill not really

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir your answer it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for your code :

```
function display(arr) {
    return arr.map((key) => `${key[0]} = ${key[1]}`)
}

const result = display([
["str", 1],
["str2", 2],
["str3", 3]
]).join(', ')

// result = "str = 1, str2 = 2, str3 = 3"
```

Comment: @ZumDummi Done.